# Constraint on characters to allow in a input field of an Xform

Tags: xml, regex, xpath, xforms, orbeon

In our scenario we need to allow only the following listed characters as input for the input field

```
     alpha/numeric
/  - Slash
-  - Hyphen
(  - Open parenthesis
)  - Close parenthesis
.  - Period
,  - Comma
’  - Single Quote
+  - Plus sign
< - Less Than
> - Greater Than
? - Question Mark
  - Space
```

Answer (score 3):

**In XPath 2.0 you can yse the [`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches) function** with a regular expression argument.

**In XPath 1.0 use**:

```
   string-length(translate(., $vallWantedChars, '')) = 0
```

The above XPath expression is true only if the string-value of the current node dosn't contain any of the unwanted characters. You need to substitute `$allunwantedChars` with a string literal or expression containing exactly any of the wanted characters.

For example, it can be:

```
concat($vAlpha, '0123456789', '/-().,+&lt;>? ', $vApos)
```

**Here is illustration of this in XSLT** (the solution is still entirely XPath 1.0, but the hosting language for the XPath processor in this case is XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="vAlpha" select=
"'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

<xsl:variable name="vApos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="vallWantedChars" select=
 "concat($vAlpha, '0123456789', '/-().,+&lt;>? ', $vApos)"/>

 <xsl:value-of select=
 "string-length(translate(., $vallWantedChars, '')) = 0"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the following XML document:**

```
<t>123^abc</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
false
```

Comment: @Vivek, and since I assume you'd like to use this from XForms, you would place the XPath expressions mentioned by @Dimitre in an `<xforms:bind contraint="..."/>` with `nodeset` attribute pointing to the node you want to validate.

Comment: @avernet: Thank you. I don't know anything about XForms, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically your regex flavour, but you could use a class character :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9/().,’+<>? -]+$
```

This will allow only the chars you mentionned (one or more times).